# ¿Cómo devolver el promedio de un cantidad de números dentro de un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, objeto

mi intención es buscar la edad promedio del siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
var amigos = [
    {amigo: 'Juan', edad: 23},
    {amigo: 'Diego', edad: 17}
    ];
```

```
function edadamigos() {
    var promedio = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++)
    var sum = amigos[i].edad.length.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
    var avg = sum/ amigos.edad.length; {
        if(sum / amigos[i].edad.length);
    }{
        promedio.push(amigos[i].edad);
    }
    return promedio;
}
```

Debería darme 20. La function que puse me da error porque no reconoce el reduce, no sé como incluir el sum y el avg dentro de este for. Cualquier recomendación y corrección se le agradecería, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El calculo es sencillo y efectivamente como mencionas tu resultado deberia de ser 20, solamente que estas dando muchas vueltas al momento de mandar a llamar las keys del objeto para la sumatoria de los resultados, ve el siguiente codigo para que te des una buena idea de como deberia hacerlo y que el codigo te quede mas simple, no se si hay alguna otra manera que sea mas corta pero trate de hacerlo lo mas entendible posible.

```js
let amigos = [
    {amigo: 'Juan', edad: 23},
    {amigo: 'Diego', edad: 17}
];

let total = 0;

amigos.map(({edad}) => total+=edad)

const resultado = total / amigos.length;

console.log(resultado)
```

La funcion `array.map()` sirve para que se recorran todos los elementos de un array de forma que puedan ser alterados en su contenido o capturar los valores de los mismos, en este caso lo que hice fue capturar el valor de `edad` y acumularlo en la variable de `total` de forma que cuando el `map` recorre todos los elementos en la suma me devolveria el valor de 40 que dividido entre 2 que es el tamanio del arreglo deberia de dar 20 como se muestra en el ejemplo.

Comment: En vista de que estas usando 'map' para responder la pregunta, puedes explicar un poco lo que hace? muchas gracias @ASASCED.

Answer (score 2):

Buscar los keys: 'edad' con map(). Luego, sumar/dividir con reduce() todos los elementos devueltos en el nuevo array para así obtener el promedio.

```
let promedio = amigos.map((edad) => edad['edad']).reduce((a,c)=> (a+c) / (amigos.length));
Console.log(promedio)
```

Saludos!